# My methods always alert Object [Object object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, return

I don't know why the methods returns always [Object object]. My code it's here:

```
function SetDataDB(){
    alert(new DatabasePlugin.get_account_profiles('settings_account'));
}

var DatabasePlugin = {
    insert_account_profiles : function(array, parameter){
        window.localStorage.setItem(parameter, array);
    },

    get_account_profiles: function(parameter){
        return "Hola";
    }
};
```

It always returns me an object but not specified. What do I have to do?

Comment: Where does `DatabasePlugin` come from?

Comment: @AlexK. the methods are on different classes so i need the new

Comment: @Asad from the homemade class DatabasePlugin :)

Comment: @MarcOrtiz Which, when instantiated, gives you an object :) What seems to be the problem?

Comment: removing `new` gets you the string, as it stands its acting as a constructor so returns an object that is a new instance of get_account_profiles (which will show as [object object] if converted to a string)

Comment: @AlexK. thanks a lot! haha horrible mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function SetDataDB(){
    alert((new DatabasePlugin).get_account_profiles('settings_account'));
}
```

I'm assuming the `get_account_profiles` of a `DatabasePlugin` instance returns a string.

EDIT: As per your edit, you need to define the object before you access its properties. Make sure `DatabasePlugin` is accessible in the scope you are invoking `SetDataDB` in.

Comment: it says me: object is not a function

Comment: @MarcOrtiz That means `DatabasePlugin` isn't a class, it is an object.

Comment: Yes it's an object. Because of this i didn't write the ()

Answer (score 1):

did you forget the parentesis ?

```
new DatabasePlugin().get_account_profiles('settings_account')
```

Comment: could you please take a look at my question edited recently? Thanks